MariaDb Docker container crash on insert
I'm using the latest MariaDb container from DockerHub (Server version: 11.3.2-MariaDB-1:11.3.2+maria~ubu2204).  It appears that every time I run a specific INSERT it crashes the server:
2024-04-09 13:45:52 information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Writing a core file...
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Resource Limits:
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max processes             unlimited            unlimited            processes 
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max open files            1048576              1048576              files     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max locked memory         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max pending signals       63274                63274                signals   
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max nice priority         0                    0                    
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us        
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Core pattern: /mnt/wslg/dumps/core.%e
2024-04-09 13:45:52 
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Kernel version: Linux version 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (root@1c602f52c2e4) (gcc (GCC) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.37) #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023
2024-04-09 13:45:52 
2024-04-09 13:45:52 Fatal signal 11 while backtracing


SELECT @group_id := id FROM `groups` WHERE name = 'olab';
SELECT @role_id := id FROM `roles` WHERE name = 'learner';
SELECT @max_id := MAX(id) FROM `users`;
SET @batch_size = @max_id / 10;
SET @num_batches = @max_id / @batch_size;

DELIMITER //
FOR l in 0..@num_batches
DO
    START TRANSACTION;
    SET @start = l * @batch_size;
    SET @end = ( l + 1 ) * @batch_size;
    INSERT INTO `user_groups` (user_id, group_id, role_id )
        SELECT id, @group_id, @role_id
        FROM `users` WHERE id >= @start and id <= @end;
    COMMIT;
END FOR;
//

I have to restart the server every time and then the query runs successfully.  It's trying to insert about 1400 rows from the 'users' table.

Since this operation is successful after a server restart please post Additional DB information, please.
OS, Version?
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after MINIMUM 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE,
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,
ulimit -a       for list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
df -h  for Used - Free space by device,
df -i  for inode info by device,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

You may want to take a quick cruise through this changelog to see if there are still open issues with MDB 11.3.2 and are affecting your instance reliability.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-11-3-2-release-notes/    Do you have an error log snippet that you could post from a previous failure caused by the 1400 row insert?

An example of managing the large number of inserts you can find in dba.stackexchange.com Question 338296 by Kondybas. The example is for DELETE activity.
Someone (maybe me) will suggest the Stored Procedure code to accomplish your INSERT in a similar manner with your calculated batch size.

Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE users; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE user_groups; for analysis.  In looking at the INSERT query, it looks like EVERY added row will have group_id as 'olab' and role_id as 'learner'.  Is that your goal?  And the user_groups will grow about 1400 rows every day.

@WilsonHauck Thanks for the suggestions!
This statement is part of a one-shot migration task to initially seed a table with data.  Once it's loaded, it's not going to change to this degree.
Please note that the problem comes from using the Official MariaDb docker container from DockerHub.  https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb Which does not have the utilities you mention.
users table: https://justpaste.it/36u69
user_groupstable: https://justpaste.it/dzc9v

Which server did the error log come from?  Could you get the additional data from that server?  Please view my profile and make contact.

Your statement involves three separate queries: two SELECTs to set variables and an INSERT using those variables. This could be causing a large transaction, especially if there are 1400 users.
Since the INSERT affects potentially all users, it might be causing locking issues during the transaction.
Instead of inserting all users at once, consider processing them in batches (e.g., 100 users at a time). This will reduce the transaction size and potential locking issues.
By default, MariaDB might be in autocommit mode, meaning each query is committed automatically. You might want to try explicitly starting a transaction before the first SELECT and committing it after the INSERT. This can help control locking behavior.

Thanks for the reply!  Adding a START TRANSACTION/COMMIT around the statements did not appear to help.  How would you 'batch' the INSERTS - something I've never had to do before....
